# How do I add a persistent static ARP entry to an AIX server?

Tags: unix, arp, aix

How do I add a persistent static ARP entry to an AIX server?

```
/> uname -a
AIX CBDIS 3 5 000B8886D700
/> uname -v
5
/> uname -r
3
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:

`arp -s 802.3 ip-address mac-address`

or, depending on the involved adapter types within AIX:

`arp -s ether ip-address mac-address`

As far as I remember these old days, there's no way to set this up via SMIT, correct me if I'm wrong.

If you're asking this trying to solve typical AIX issue with wrong MAC staying too long in your ARP table, consider changing `arpt_killc` parameter with a `no` command to a lower value, default is something around 20 minutes if I remember correctly.

Comment: actually, the issue is that ARP is resolving the wrong MAC for a specific IP, adding the static entry solves the problem, but I would love to figure out why the dynamic behavior is getting it wrong, it's resolving the IP to the MAC of the default gateway

Comment: Well, you need to do a tcpdump session to see who's publishing this rogue record on the network. AIX here acts as "bad guy", cause by default it would remember these rogue records for 20 minutes. If you lower `arpt_killc` (it's a timeout to clear stale "complete" ARP entries) you should suffer much less :)